# Cannot cast Class to Interface from dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I have the following class

```
namespace WAM.Modules.AlertScanner
{
  public class Module : IModule
  {
    private Page _main;
    private Page _options;
    private String _name;
    private ViewModels.AlertScanner _scanner;

    public Page MainPage()
    {
        return _main;
    }

    public Page OptionsPage()
    {
        return _options;
    }

    public string Name()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public Module()
    {
        _name = "Alert Scanner";
        _scanner = new ViewModels.AlertScanner();
        _main = new Views.Main(_scanner.Main_Data);
        _options = new Views.Options(_scanner.Options_Data);
    }
  }
}
```

And an interface

```
namespace WAM.Shared.Interfaces
{
  interface IModule
  {
    Page MainPage();

    Page OptionsPage();

    String Name();
  }
}
```

I want to be able to load at runtime a dll containing a class called "Module" with an interface "IModule" and cast it to said interface.

I found the following code on SO and changed it a bit to get the following

```
string fullpath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullpath);
Type t = ass.GetType("WAM.Modules.AlertScanner.Module");
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
IModule module = (IModule)o;
Console.WriteLine("Module : {0}", module.Name());
```

However, VS always crashes at the casting part saying

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'WAM.Modules.AlertScanner.Module' to type 'WAM.Shared.Interfaces.IModule'."}

**UPDATE :**

Currently i only have one dll : WAM.Modules.AlertScanner.dll

There is also only one exe : WAM.Desktop.exe

There are 3 projects in the solution :

- WAM.Desktop (Windows Aplication)
- WAM.Shared (Shared Project)
- WAM.AlertScanner (Class Library)

There are too many classes to list here but the ones used in this context :

- Module (WAM.Modules.AlertScanner)
- IModule (WAM.Shared)
- ManagerModules (WAM.Shared)

ManagerModules is supposed to load, at runtime, DLLs that have a class called Module that inherits IModule. WAM.Shared is referenced in WAM.Desktop (the one using the manager) and in WAM.Modules.AlertScanner (for the inheritance).

**UPDATE 2 :**

The problem seems to be that my code generates 2 versions of the interface.

Is there a way to make it so only one version of the interface is kept?

Comment: You have two different versions of the interface loaded.  You need to avoid that.

Comment: Could you explain where you see that? And also, how i could avoid that?

Comment: Can you post the names of the DLLs and EXEs + which DLL/EXE has what classes / interfaces?

Comment: Right click and click on "Go to Definition" on the `IModule` in AlertScanner, then Right click and click on "Go to Definition" on the `IModule` in `IModule module = (IModule)o;` Does it take you to the same file in the same assembly? The error you are getting is usually the one you get when the answer to my last question is "No, it takes me to two different assemblies" (even if both assemblies use the same file on the hard drive because you used "Add Existing->Link" when you added the file to the assembly's project).

Comment: After going to sleep, removing my fatigue in the process, i see your point and i think you are correct. I've updated the question to reflect the new information.

Comment: if someone called `ass.GetType` on me the return value would be `Ass.Large`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i didn't get any clear answer about my question and i managed to correct the problem, i'm posting my solution in case anyone else has the same problem :

- As stated by others, i had one version of the interface in each assembly, which was the cause of the errors.
- The reason for those multiple versions was that i added the interface in a shared project. Shared projects help centralizing code, however at compilation each assembly make the code it's own which results in the situation i was in.
- The solution is rather simple : move the interface in another assembly (i moved it in a class library) and add references to that assembly in the assemblies using the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Class  `WAM.Modules.AlertScanner.Module` implements  `WAM.Modules.AlertScanner.IModule`. You are trying to cast to `WAM.Shared.Interfaces.IModule`. Thought `WAM.Modules.AlertScanner.IModule` and `WAM.Shared.Interfaces.IModule` look the same, have the same signature, they are different because they are in different namespaces. You need to write adapter from `WAM.Modules.AlertScanner.IModule` to `WAM.Shared.Interfaces.IModule`

Comment: Wait, that is what i don't understand. I don't have a class WAM.Modules.AlertScanner.IModule.

Comment: I've generated adapter class with CodDom, compiled it into assembly. When I'm trying to get instace of adapter I get exception "Unable load "WAM.Modules.AlertScanner, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"" thought it in current domain assabmlies. If refer this assemble to project it works. I'm trying to resolve this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm having a hard time understanding your comment.